# VBA Cómo mantenerse logueado en una página web y manipular html

Tags: html, excel, web, vba, login

me estoy volviendo loco pero creo que así se aprende mejor.
Resulta que usando vba desde excel entro a una página web donde ingreso mi usuario y contraseña y envío la información (he usado Internetexplorer.application), luego se carga otra url y sé que tendrá éxito sólo si estoy logueado.
En esta página nueva yo ingresaría unos datos y clickearía unos botones (no tengo problemas con esto).
He intentado con Internetexplorer.application y con MSXML2.XMLHTTP60.

No sé cómo poder trabajar en esta nueva página, no puedo capturar su html y para colmo luego de ingresar la información que necesito en esta nueva página se abre otra, ahora debo trabajar los elementos html acá y necesito volver a la anterior y así sucesivamente.
**Me conviene trabajar con Iexplorer o con MSXML2.XMLHTTP60? Y cómo capturar los nuevos html?**

```
Sub HT()
Dim extranet As String
Dim nurl As String
Dim u As String, p As String
Dim d As New HTMLDocument
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim BOT As HTMLElementCollection

extranet = "URL"
u = "USER"
p = "PASS"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", extranet, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send

d.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
d.getElementById("vUSUCOD").Value = u
d.getElementById("vUSUCLA").Value = p
d.getElementsByName("IMAGE1")(0).Click

'RECOGER HTML2 y TRABAJAR CON EL
'RECOGER HTML3 y TRABAJAR CON EL
'VOLVER A HYML2...

End s¿Sub
```

Comment: Sin ver la web ni nada, entiendo que quieres hacer scrapping, así que sería mejor usar Iexplorer...

Comment: En realidad no quiero sacar información, sino entrar a un portal de mi trabajo con mi usuario y contraseña y tocar unos botones de unas inspecciones de vehículos que debo revisar, el caso es que hay unos miles atrasados y hay qu entrar a cada una, escribir el mismo texto en una casilla y dar un reprobado en un botón. Por eso pensé automatizarlo. Alguna ideas de cómo mantenerme logueado para poder seguir esos links sin perder la sesión? Intenté con IEXPLORER también pero me falta mucho conocimiento.